# how to do inner join on the first row of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
   SELECT p.`id` , p.`name` , pp.`name` 
FROM  `product` p
INNER JOIN  `product_picture` pp ON p.id = pp.product_id
```

and then this gives me the following result:

[image]

However I only wanted to get only one product picture for each item (which is the first one on top). So I wanted to get a query that returns:

```
7     Glavins Necklace   83081c5619068f6ec700e12d827d2199745c8283.jpeg
8     Woodsie Bracelet   83081c5619068f6ec700e12d827d2199745c8283.jpeg
```

How do I do so?

Comment: How do you identify the top picture? And do you really want the same picture for both id's?

Comment: @Goat_CO So the top picture is essentially the one that has the smallest product_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregate `MIN()` or `MAX()` to pick one picture

```
SELECT p.`id` , p.`name` , MIN(pp.`name`) picture
  FROM  `product` p INNER JOIN  `product_picture` pp 
    ON p.id = pp.product_id
 GROUP BY p.`id` , p.`name`
```

Comment: why do I need the MIN here? I tried removing the min and it worked, just by adding the group by

Comment: Since MySql allows you to specify a column that is not part of a `GROUP BY` you can omit it. But other "normal" RDBMSes don't allow you to do this, because it's unclear what row within a group RDBMS should choose? Using `MIN()` or other aggregate you're telling specifically what row to choose. Read more on that here **[MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)**

Comment: and also minor stuff, but referencing MIN(pp. `name`) as picture is useless?

Comment: Since you have two columns in the resultset with the same name `name` you better give one of them (or both) explicit names (aliases).